# Complexity calculation using a recurrence relation

Tags: complexity-theory, recurrence-relation, induction, factorial

I just can't solve this problem, I'm new to reccurences. I have this recurrence

$T(n)=n*T(n-1)$
$T(1)=1$

The second term will be:

$T(n-1)=(n-1)*T(n-2)$

And so on.

It's complexity is **O(n!)** but i don't know how to solve it.

I hope you can help me with an idea!

Comment: First, be clear about what you mean by "complexity of a recurrence relation". Do you simply want to solve the recurrence, or determine the computational cost of evaluating it (naively following the definition)?

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Prove by induction on $n$ that $T(n) = n!$.

Note that a recurrence relation doesn't have a *complexity*. Rather, it defines a function. In many cases, this function is the running time of some algorithm, and then the time complexity of the *algorithm* is the solution to the recurrence.

Comment: If we're being careful about terminology, algorithms don't have a complexity but running time. Complexity is a property of problems.